# Ruby code throwing Exception in Rufus Scheduler

Tags: ruby, rufus-scheduler, tiny-tds

I am executing a controller on debian linux which performs a functionality in a infinite loop. Along with this I am using Rufus Scheduler to schedule a function which runs after a specific amount of time lets say 1 min. Once the functions executes in Rufus properly I get the following error

```
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:505:   [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000000
    ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-linux]

    -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
    c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :sleep
    c:0002 p:0041 s:0004 e:000003 BLOCK  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:505 [FINISH]
    c:0001 p:---- s:0002 e:000001 TOP    [FINISH]

    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:505:in `block in start'
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/rufus-scheduler-3.0.4/lib/rufus/scheduler.rb:505:in `sleep'

    -- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1b8bba) [0x2b1903679bba] vm_dump.c:685
     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x7414c) [0x2b190353514c] error.c:307
     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(rb_bug+0xb8) [0x2b1903535458] error.c:334
     /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x13be39) [0x2b19035fce39] signal.c:704
    /lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xeff0) [0x2b190396cff0]
    /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5(+0x16a05) [0x2b1908457a05]
    /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5(+0x3cdcb) [0x2b190847ddcb]
    /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5(+0x3d5f1) [0x2b190847e5f1]
    /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5(+0x3d70b) [0x2b190847e70b]
    /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5(+0x2909e) [0x2b190846a09e]
    /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5(+0x290c9) [0x2b190846a0c9]
    /usr/lib/libsybdb.so.5(dbsqlok+0x85) [0x2b1908451a15]
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/tiny_tds-0.6.1/tiny_tds/tiny_tds.so(+0x44f1) [0x2b1907ff24f1] result.c:89
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1c73c2) [0x2b19036883c2] thread.c:1263
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/tiny_tds-0.6.1/tiny_tds  /tiny_tds.so(+0x5966) [0x2b1907ff3966] result.c:133
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1a1c9a) [0x2b1903662c9a] vm_insnhelper.c:1468
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1a5a01) [0x2b1903666a01] insns.def:1028
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1ab38c) [0x2b190366c38c] vm.c:1304
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1b01bb) [0x2b19036711bb] vm.c:732
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(rb_rescue2+0x113) [0x2b1903539443] eval.c:751
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x19e49e) [0x2b190365f49e] vm_eval.c:1042
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1a1c9a) [0x2b1903662c9a] vm_insnhelper.c:1468
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1b6a20) [0x2b1903677a20] vm_insnhelper.c:1558
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1a61a7) [0x2b19036671a7] insns.def:999
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x1ab38c) [0x2b190366c38c] vm.c:1304
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(rb_iseq_eval_main+0x300) [0x2b190366c9b0] vm.c:1562
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(+0x78a4a) [0x2b1903539a4a] eval.c:253
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(ruby_exec_node+0x1d) [0x2b1903539a7d] eval.c:318
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/libruby.so.2.1(ruby_run_node+0x1e) [0x2b190353b2fe] eval.c:310
ruby() [0x40098b]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x2b190445fc8d]
ruby() [0x400879]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's an exception that's being thrown from a native library, not Ruby itself.  It looks like the root cause might be in the tiny_tds gem you're using:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/tiny_tds-0.6.1/tiny_tds/tiny_tds.so(+0x44f1) [0x2b1907ff24f1] result.c:89
```

Have you tried upgrading to a later version of tiny_tds to see whether the problem persists?

edit: I see it is the latest version; perhaps raise this with the tiny_tds maintainers - see https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds

Comment: I went through the documentation and tried to install free tds with --with switch but the error still persists. Is this the incompatibility of gem or gems or could be error in the code causing such exception to occur.

Comment: It looks like this is a bug in native code, not in the gems themselves, which is why I suggested taking it up with the maintainers.  https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/blob/master/ext/tiny_tds/result.c#L89 is the line raising the error, and it looks like GET_CLIENT_USERDATA above is returning a null reference - when this is dereferenced the segfault is raised.

Comment: What I should then to rectify this problem.